# spyOn with argumented function in javascript. gives me error TypeError: e is undefined

Tags: jquery, jasmine

I am writting test case for javascript using jasmine but when I am creating spyOn to a function  and calling loginSubmit it is giving me error "TypeError: e is undefined" in that perticular function.

My test code is as below:

```
 describe('this will test for html fixtures and login function called', function (){

    beforeEach(function() {
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/spec/javascripts/fixtures';
        loadFixtures('login.fixtures.html');
    });

    it('expect fixtures to exist', function() {
        expect('form').toExist();
        expect('form').toContainElement('button');
    });
    spyOn(window, $.fn.loginSubmit());
    $('.submit').click();

    it('expect function to be called', function(){
        expect(loginSubmit).toBeCalled();
    });
    });
```

and Javascript code is as:

```
$.fn.loginSubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // my whole functionality
    };
```

Please tell me what is wrong with this code and suggest me if I am doing something wrong. I am newbee in testing frontend javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `spyOn()` should be the object that contains the function to be spied on, and the second argument should be a **string** representing the name of the function to be spied on. This can be seen in the example spec file in the [Jasmine documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Spies).

In your case, if you are trying to spy on the `loginSubmit()` function on `window.$.fn`, you should call:

```
spyOn(window.$.fn, 'loginSubmit');
```

Looking at your code though, I'm not sure that you need the reference to `window`, so you might just call:

```
spyOn($.fn, 'loginSubmit');
```

The error you are currently seeing occurs because you are actually *invoking* the `loginSubmit()` function when you mean to be spying on it. This function expects an argument to be passed to it, which you have named `e` in your JavaScript code. However, since the test invokes `loginSubmit()` without any arguments, your code is rightfully complaining that `e is undefined`.

Comment: Thank you Nathan for reply. Actually loginSubmit function is being called on the submit of form. So how I will pass that e(event) in spyOn function so that test case will work or will I do something else?